# relations in SELECT query (PHP)

Tags: php, mysql

I have little problem with SQL query in PHP.
I want to get from table `post` rows with category ex. 'art'.
This table don't contain name of my category (only category_id).
So, how to connect this in my query?

Tables:

```
post:

id, title, category_id

category:

id, name
```

I tried this way, but it not works.

```
SELECT * FROM post WHERE category_id = category.id AND category.name="art";
```

Anyone can help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the JOIN

```
SELECT * FROM post 
INNER JOIN category 
WHERE category_id = category.id AND category.name="art";
```

Comment: Thanks for uppercasing the keywords.  That is a practice IMO that makes things a LOT easier to read...

Comment: thank you @cale_b i think the OP also appears to follow this practice. Good for him

Answer (score 3):

You need to [join](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html) the tables.

Given your schema, this should give you an starting point:

```
SELECT p.* FROM post p INNER JOIN category c ON p.category_id = c.id WHERE c.name = 'art';
```

Comment: Or `INNER JOIN category c ON p.category_id = c.id AND c.name = 'art'`....

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `join` to query on `name` column of category table, e.g.:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM post p JOIN category c ON p.category_id = c.id
WHERE c.name = 'art';
```